# Capturing text elements as variables

Tags: php, json, wikidata

I am trying to capture the first instance of particular elements from an object. I have an object $doc and would like to get the values of the following.

id, url, alias, description and label i.e. specifically:

- variable1 - Q95,
- variable2 - //www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q95,
- variable3 - Google.Inc,
- varialbe4 - American multinational Internet and technology corporation,
- variable5 - Google

I've made some progress getting the $jsonArr string however I'm not sure this is the best way to go, and if so I'm not sure how to progress anyway. 
Please advise as to the best way to get these. Please see my code below:

```
<HTML>
<body>
<form method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="Google"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
$search = $_POST['q']; 
$errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);    
$doc = new DOMDocument();     
$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?
action=wbsearchentities&search=$search&format=json&language=en");    
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($errors); 

var_dump($doc);
echo "<p>";
$jsonArr = $doc->documentElement->nodeValue;

$jsonArr = (string)$jsonArr;
echo $jsonArr; 

}
?>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the response to your API request is JSON, not HTML or XML, it's most appropriate to use cURL or Stream library to perform the HTTP request. You can even use something primitive like [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

For example, using cURL:

```
// Make the request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=google&format=json&language=en");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the string into an appropriate PHP type
$contents = json_decode($output);

// Navigate the object
$contents->search[0]->id; // "Q95"
$contents->search[0]->url; // "//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q95"
$contents->search[0]->aliases[0]; // "Google Inc."
```

You can use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to inspect the `$contents` and traverse it like you would any PHP object.